# Count date range based on criteria

Tags: excel

Let´s suppose I have generated a report with dates (day/month/year) when soccer teams won titles. This is how the report is going to look like:

| Area | Team | Champions League | Europe League |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| England | Chelsea | 27/01/2021 | 15/01/2021 |
| Spain | Real Madri | 27/02/2021 | 20/01/2021 |
| Spain | Barcelona |  | 18/02/2021 |
| France | PSG | 27/03/2021 | 27/02/2021 |

My objective here is going to count how many titles each area won per month. So, this is how my desired output looks like:

| Area | January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| England | 2 |  |  |
| Spain | 1 | 2 |  |
| France |  | 1 | 1 |

What I tried to do was the following (for January and England):

```
=COUNTIFS(Table[[#All],[Champions League]:[Europe League]],">01/01/2021",Table[[#All],[Champions League]:[Europe League]],"<31/01/2022",Table[[#All],[Area]],"=England")
```

However, my output using this formula is "#VALUE!". Can you please help trying to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this as shown in image below, so I have used the **incredibly versatile** `SUMPRODUCT Function` to achieve the expected output

**Formula used in cell B8 Fill Down & Fill Right**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A8=$A$2:$A$5)*(B$7=TEXT($C$2:$D$5,"mmmm"))*($C$2:$D$5<>""))
```

To hide the zeros, you may custom format the cells by pressing **CTRL 1 --> Format Cells --> Number Tab --> Category --> Custom --> Type --> `0;;`**

[image: COUNT DATE RANGE BASED ON CRITERIA]

### EDIT

**Approach Using Power Query**

[image: END_RESULT]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table39"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Area", type text}, {"Team", type text}, {"Champions League", type date}, {"Europe League", type date}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Area", "Team"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Extracted Month Name" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {{"Value", each Date.MonthName(_), type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Extracted Month Name", {"Area"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Area=nullable text, Team=nullable text, Attribute=text, Value=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Value", "Index"}, {"Value", "Index"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"All"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Value]), "Value", "Index", List.NonNullCount)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Using **Power Query** will be **dynamic**, **one time operation** and every time add new data to the original source the imported table from Power Query gets updated within few by a **single refresh**, please follow the steps

• First select any cell within the range,

• Then from **Data Tab** under **Get & Transform Data**, Click **From Table/Range**,

[image: STEP_1]

• A pop up shall appear, check mark the **My table has headers** and press Ok

[image: STEP_1.1]

• Data gets loaded into **Power Query Editor**

• Change the name of the table from **Query Settings** in the right hand under Properties with **CountTbl**

[image: STEP_2]

• Now select any column and press CTRL A

• If the **Changed Type Step is already showing in Applied steps** then you **don't have to follow this**, please goto the next step

From **Transform Tab** --> Click **Detect Data Type**

[image: STEP_3]

• Now you will find the **dates are still showing as Time Stamps** therefore select both `Champions League` & `Europa League` Columns and from **Transform Tab** --> Click **Data Type from Any to Date only**, you shall get a message asking whether to **Replace the current step or to add new step**, you need to select the **Replace**

[image: STEP_4]

• Well data types changed, now select the **Area** and **Team** Columns and press **Right Click Unpivot Other Columns** also you may find the option from **Transform Tab** --> **Unpivot Columns dropdown** and select **Unpivot Other Columns**

[image: STEP_5]

• Next, select the Value column showing dates --> Goto **Transform Tab** --> From **Date & Time Column Group** --> Click **Date** --> **Month** --> **Name Of Month**

[image: STEP_6]

• Again select the **Area** Column --> From **Transform** Tab --> **Group By** --> Give any fancy name to the **New Column Name** --> **Operation** --> **All Rows and press OK**

[image: STEP_7]

• Now goto **Add Column Tab** --> Click **Custom Column** and enter this following Formula or the **M-Code** in custom column formula space

```
Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)
```

**press Ok**

[image: STEP_8]

• So from the custom column newly created, click on the **dropdown**, and **uncheck the box use original column name as prefix** and select the columns **Value and Index and press Ok**

[image: STEP_9]

• Remove the column which we created by **Group i.e. All** --> Select the column and press **delete key from your keyboard**

[image: STEP_10]

• Now select the value column which will be showing the **month name** and goto **Transform Tab** and click **Pivot Column**

[image: STEP_11]

• There Values Column needs to be **Index** and in **Advanced Options** you to select **Count (Not Blank)** and **press OK**

[image: STEP_12]

• You shall see the **expected output has been achieved!!!**

[image: STEP_13]

• From **Home** Tab Click **Close & Load To** --> **Import Data** --> **Table** --> You can either select **Existing Worksheet (enter the cell reference where you want to place the imported table) or New Worksheet** and press Ok

[image: STEP_14]

**IMPORT DATA**

[image: STEP_14.1]

• **Done** **[Full_Explanation](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlEkksoPTc2cgyqwTEh0gxFGaGq4?e=Lx7GEi) [Power_Query](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cgysW_hfY9ud1Xl4C?e=euNSad)**

Comment: Amazing! But could you please send me the file you worked on to check the formula you used with the SUMPRODUCT Function in order for me to find my mistake? Cause it is giving me different values when following the exact same formula you provided me. Rn it is giving me "0" instead of 2. The explanation for the power query part is perfect.

Comment: @PedroTavares Sir, check the link beside `Done` i.e. `Full Explanation` & `Power Query`- I have also shared the whole tutorial with `Power Query` as well

Comment: I already watched the "Full Explanation" link you provided me but I couldn´t find the explanation of the first part (without using power query)

Comment: @PedroTavares Sir, i have not created any explanation for the `SUMPRODUCT` , ok let me add in the workbook which i have attached as link, will that be okay with you

Comment: Yes it will be perfect, it is the only thing that I want to check!

Comment: @PedroTavares Sir, updated in the workbook link `Power Query`

Answer (score 1):

COUNTIFS doesn't like your dissimilar sized criteria ranges.

You would be better served setting your data up in a tabular format like so:

| Area | Team | Championship | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| England | Chelsea | Champions League | 1/27/2021 |
| England | Chelsea | Europe League | 1/15/2021 |
| Spain | Real Madri | Champions League | 2/27/2021 |
| Spain | Real Madri | Europe League | 1/20/2021 |
| Spain | Barcelona | Europe League | 2/18/2021 |
| France | PSG | Champions League | 3/27/2021 |
| France | PSG | Europe League | 2/27/2021 |

You get your data into this format easily by using Power Query.  Simply load the data in, select the two date columns, and Unpivot.

[image]

And then you could use a simple Pivot Table to display the data in your preferred format:

[image]

To turn the full date to just the Month name select one cell > right-click > Group > by Month

Comment: The problem is that I can´t set my data like this =(

Comment: @PedroTavares I edited the answer to show how to simply unpivot your data.  Its easier to get your data into the proper format then it is to find workarounds to display it properly.